# UWP "Access to the path '...' is denied" when trying to write a json file to the app directory

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm new to UWP, but I've been using C# (desktop applications, etc) for a long time. I recently tried writing to a json file in the app directory like I usually would, and I got this message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\...\setting.json' is denied
```

This was the code I was using:

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "setting.json"), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Settings));
```

I though that was weird so I did some research. It seems the app directory is read-only. I've tried setting the attribute to "Normal", still the same error. I've tried using StorageFolder and StorageFile, still the same message. Is there some way to make the folder not read-only? This worked just fine in a WPF app...

Comment: You shouldn't be putting files in your application directory. Just because it "worked" in WPF didn't mean it was right. There's a page on [Storing and retrieving settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) that's specifically written for UWP developers. (Also, assuming that the current directory is meaningful is usually a good way of shooting yourself in the foot. Outside of early startup, it's safest to assume it's not pointing anywhere useful)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not declared [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) capability in `Package.appxmanifest` file. And `broadFileSystemAccess` allow all files that the user has access to. For example: documents, pictures, photos, downloads, desktop, OneDrive, etc.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Please note in addition to specifying the capability, the `rescap` namespace must be added, and is also added to `gnorableNamespaces`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I record file internaly for my apps :

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder roamingFolder;
string donnees = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anobject);
if (UseRoaming)
{
    roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
}
else
{
    roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
}
StorageFile sampleFile = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(textStream))
    {
        textWriter.WriteString(donnees);
        await textWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps